# Prevent Angular PWA from updating automatically

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, auto-update, angular-service-worker

Angular-PWA can be a good choice for my recent startup project. But one of its nice features must be disabled!

The app will have sensitive data and must be stable during a long period of time (until the user chooses *Update* explicitly). So it must not be updated automatically.

[The official documentation of Angular's Service-worker](https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-config) doesn't include any idea around this strategy.

Is there any idea?

Comment: Your code should control the calls to the backend to send & fetch data. If you can describe the problem you are having in your specific app, perhaps we could offer some suggestions.

Comment: @Mathias - The problem is not complex. You know if we update our backend files (`index.html`, etc) then Angular Service-worker on user's browser will detect the changes (almost immediately) and downloads new files. And the updated app starts on the next launch. *This must not occur!* Alternatively, the user should have a choice to update the app manually. Just like many other native apps we know. Like IntelliJ IDEA, etc. But not like Google Chrome!

Comment: On the other hand is Firefox browser. It has both options: **1. Automatically install updates** / **2. Check for updates but let you choose to install them**. *Our app must be like the second.*

Comment: @Mathias - A scenario can be to register a ***wrapper Service-worker***. It must do two works: **1. register the main Service-worker** / **2. prevent it from fetching *up-to-date* `ngsw.json` and feed it by a cached version** (until the user chooses the *Update*).

Comment: When a user changes their sensitive data, you are not saving that to a backend database?

Comment: @Mathias; Excuse me for delay. No, they aren't saved to a backend database. I also posted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are totally 3 places that Angular's Service-worker tries to checking update. First on an explicit request (OK) and ***two others (`check-updates-on-navigation` and `init post-load (update)`) are automated*** and must be disabled. See below patch (for `@angular/service-worker v7.1.0`):

```
--- "node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js"   1985-10-26 11:45:00.000000000 +0330
+++ "node_modules/@angular/service-worker/ngsw-worker.js"   2019-02-13 23:28:10.828903500 +0330
@@ -1990 +1990 @@
-                    const action = (() => __awaiter$5(this, void 0, void 0, function* () { yield this.checkForUpdate(); }))();
+                    const action = (() => __awaiter$5(this, void 0, void 0, function* () { console.log('WILL_UPDATE_ON_EXPLICIT_MESSAGE'); yield this.checkForUpdate(); }))();
@@ -2101 +2101 @@
-                        yield this.checkForUpdate();
+                        console.log('DISCARDED: check-updates-on-navigation'); //yield this.checkForUpdate();
@@ -2171 +2171 @@
-                        yield this.checkForUpdate();
+                        console.log('DISCARDED: init post-load (update)'); //yield this.checkForUpdate();
```

*But I don't use this risky way.*